# Transfer Learning - How can I change only the output layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to apply one idea proposed by Rusu et al. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06295.pdf, which consists in training a NN changing the output layer according to the class of the input, i.e., provided that we know the id of the input, we would pick the corresponding output layer. This way, all the hidden layers would be trained with all the data, but each output layer would only be trained with its corresponding type of input data.

This is meant to achieve good results in a transfer learning framework.

How can I implement this "change of the last layer" in tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [model subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#building_models), you can actually define you forward pass.

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.block_1 = BlockA()
        self.block_2 = BlockB()
        self.global_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.classifier = Dense(num_classes)

    def call(self, inputs):
        if condition:
            x = self.block_1(inputs)
        else:
            x = self.block_2(inputs)
        x = self.global_pool(x)
        return self.classifier(x)
```

You'll still have the backprop part to figure out, but I think it's fairly easy if you use a multioutput model and train all your "last layers" at the same time.

Comment: The approach I thought of in the first place was similar to that, but then I had problems in the backprop part. What do you mean by training the last layers "at the same time"? I mean, I would only want to train the last layer that corresponds to the type of input used...

Comment: Training your model with multiple inputs and outputs. For example if you a train a digit and a dog/cat classifier, you'll input one batch from the digit dataset AND another batch from the dog/cat dataset at the same time. And you'll have two one-hot vectors as an output.

Comment: I don’t quite understand the concept of multi inputs... that would mean that my hidden layers (at least the first one) would also have to change size, right? What I really want was to keep the structure of the hidden layers and call it followed by the output layer corresponding to the class of the input.